# right join does not work properly

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables as follow:

[image]

when I use the following command I get the following result:

```
SELECT A.enid AS enid, sum(A.comment) AS Comments, B.enname
FROM ee.entity_epoch A
right JOIN ee.entity B
ON A.id = B.enid group by A.enid
```

Result:

[image]

But according to the following link:

[joins](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)
since I use right join I expect to get the records for saman and reza with column of comment as null. I am so confused can anyone says how can I get records with saman and reza and null for comment column plus the result shown above?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what happens if you switch the tables and use a left join instead?

Comment: I get the same result!

Comment: It's tagged MySQL and I use T-SQL, but are you allowed to only `GROUP BY` 1 of the columns you're selecting? Don't you need to add `B.enname `since you're selecting that as well?

Comment: you can use a WHERE clause if you want comment column to be null. The comment does not appear in the ON clause, the difference between inner/outer/left/right JOINs happens when you join ON a column that may have a null value.

Comment: Thanks RobP but according to the link that I posted at the end there is an example that is exactly like my scenario and in that link right join is used and the result as you can see in that link is exactly what I want to get here

Comment: @Trafz Yes I can do that and I do not get any error:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want a subquery here before the join.

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT enid
             , SUM(COMMENT) AS Comments
          FROM entity_epoch
          GROUP BY enid) a
        RIGHT JOIN
        entity B ON A.enid = B.enid
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b0da3/10)

Personally I would reorder and make it a left join for readability, but it doesn't make any functional difference.

This can also be done as:

```
SELECT A.enid AS enid
      ,SUM(A.Comment) Comments
      , B.enname
  FROM entity_epoch A
       RIGHT JOIN 
       entity B
       ON A.enid = B.enid 
GROUP BY b.enid
```

[sqlfiddlee](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e079b2/5)

I'd be curiosu to see the different in exectuon plan, but don't have MySQL available.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your helpful answer. The problem is that I have a very big database and I use the something like above code with left join instead and it works fine so I do not want inner selection because it affects speed.( Also I updated my question above about nullability. I meant -2 and -5 for columns of comment instead) is there any way that I can get the result without using inner selection and something similar to the query that I wrote?

Comment: Sorry I guess I was right about nullability so no worry about that

Comment: Also I check your query and the result is exactly what I want without but preferably without inner selection

Comment: Your attempt is joining A.id = B.enid when you want to join on A.enid = b.enid. See my update.

Comment: Some people are born to be unique and helpful for the society. You are one of them.:)

Answer (score 1):

reza and saman both have matches in A, so no "Comments is NULL" records from A are generated for them.  Are you sure you didn't want

`SELECT A.enid AS enid, sum(A.comment) AS Comments, B.enname
FROM ee.entity_epoch A
right JOIN ee.entity B
ON A.enid = B.enid group by A.enid`

?

Comment: Please see the update and what is the difference between what I posted and yours?(I think they are the same queries)

Comment: In your OP, the last line is different from what I wrote.  I changed A.id to A.enid.